# Global Function that can be accessed across all sheets in an excel workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function that I am using in a sheet but I now wish to use it in another sheet.

```
Function IsTextEmpty(t As String) As Boolean
    If Trim(t & vbNullString) = "" Then
        IsTextEmpty = True
    Else
        IsTextEmpty = False
    End If
End Function
```

I tried adding it as is to ThisWorkbook but that doesn't allow it to be accessed from my sheets. Is there anywhere I can place a function so it can be accessed via any sheet and if this is the way, could I be calling it wrong or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Put it in a regular code module.

Comment: If it's in `ThisWorkbook`, other modules _in the same project_ can access it by _qualifying_ the member call, e.g. `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.IsTextEmpty("test")`. Moving it to a standard module also makes it available to _other projects_ that might reference this one.